# Virtual method from a static context

Tags: c#, oop

I have a `BaseProgram` which acts as a base class for all other programs.
I want to add an overridable method `HandleException()`  to this class for error-handling.
All the programs deriving from this BaseProgram should have the option to write their own version of `HandleException()`.

So, I got to declare `HandleException()` as a `virtual` method as below:

```
abstract class BaseProgram
{
    public abstract void Run();

    public static void RunWithExceptionHandling(BaseProgram programToRun)
    {
        try
        {
            //do some processing 
            programToRun.Run();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
           HandleException();  //Error : Can't access non-static method in static context
        }
    }

    public virtual void HandleException()
    { 
        //Do some basic exception handling here
    }
}
```

But I can't call this new virtual method in catch block of static method:    `RunWithExceptionHandling()` 
Also, due to application design I can't change `RunWithExceptionHandling` from `static` to non-`static` :-(

Any  ideas how can I work-around this issue so I can allow derived class to have their own version of `HandleException()`?

Comment: why not just call programToRun.HandleException() in your catch clause?

Comment: yes, you cannot do this with static declared methods. ideally you should create a non static class and have it override in its child classes. why can you not change the design to be a proper designed class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you have the instance with you; you just need to use it to invoke the method. That would call the derived version of `HandleException` if one exist.

```
public static void RunWithExceptionHandling(BaseProgram programToRun)
{
    try
    {
        //do some processing 
        programToRun.Run();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
       programToRun.HandleException();//Use the instance :)
    }
}
```

Comment: good work around however the concern here is that you are giving this method complete access to the BaseProgram instance. ideally you want to avoid that. there is a lot of potential for it to be misusing/abusing the instance (calling other methods when it shouldn't be etc...) and generally, just doesn't "feel" the right way of doing it (but as I said, it is a workaround!)

Comment: @Ahmedilyas I'd like to know what could be the right way to do it? Extract a interface with required methods and use it? Or something else? I don't see any problem as the method name is `RunWithExceptionHandling` it just calls `Run` and `HandleException`; both actions are conveyed from the name itself isn't it?

Comment: Sure but what i was saying was that it is more prone to abuse ot misuse by another developer or the lifetime of the application. The right way would of course be to design it correctly in the first instance :)